# How does the supposed "Unified Architecture for NLP" from Collobert and Weston 2008 really works?

Tags: nlp, neural-network

In this paper ([here](http://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2008_nlp_icml.pdf))  they suppose a "unified architecture for NLP" with deep neural networks with multitask learning

My problem is to understand the layered architecture in figure 1, see below:
[image: unified deep learning architecture for NLP]

1. Is someone able to give me a concrete, reproducible example of how this architecture processing 3 sentences through their layers?
2. What are the outputs after each layer?
3. Why they choose which layer?